# How can I get Wordpress to save comments in markdown format?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, markdown

I love markdown, and I have  the Wordpress [markdown-for-wordpress-and-bbpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/markdown-for-wordpress-and-bbpress/) parsing markdown in my posts and comments.

However, I've noticed that Wordpress saves the comments rendered in html format.  This makes it more difficult to go back and edit comments.  How can I get wordpress to save comments in markdown format?

I couldn't find a plugin for it.  Maybe there's an easy php hack?

#### Edit:

Maybe it's not builtin to wordpress.  Comments normally not saved with any markup without the markdown plugin.  Could be a  markdown-for-wordpress-and-bbpress "feature" / accident?

Cross-posted to [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/how-can-i-get-wordpress-to-save-comments-in-markdown-format).  BAinternet had some good ideas of saving markup for comments like in the markup-on-save plugin, but no working solution yet.

#### Partial hack

*may help?  May be theme-dependent.  Lists still get saved rendered sometimes.*

In `wp-content/plugins/markdown-for-wordpress-and-bbpress/markdown.php` comment out the `pre_comment_content` markdown filter

```
 if (MARKDOWN_WP_COMMENTS) {
    remove_filter('comment_text', 'wpautop', 30);
    remove_filter('comment_text', 'make_clickable');
    #HACK don't save comments rendered in HTML
    #add_filter('pre_comment_content', 'Markdown', 6);
    add_filter('pre_comment_content', 'mdwp_hide_tags', 8);
    add_filter('pre_comment_content', 'mdwp_show_tags', 12);
    add_filter('get_comment_text',    'Markdown', 6);
    add_filter('get_comment_excerpt', 'Markdown', 6);
    add_filter('get_comment_excerpt', 'mdwp_strip_p', 7);
```

Comment: Good question, although I don't think there is going to be an easy PHP hack for this.

Comment: hmm, I smell a plugin opportunity! also, you might have better luck in our sister wordpress site

Answer (score 2):

Nice question. As this feature is not available in the Wordpress plugin, **you'll need to do some hackery** at least to stop it from saving in HTML format, which you have done.

Now you need for when the comments are displayed to **process that markdown into HTML.** So let's use the `comment_text` hook:

```
<?php add_filter('comment_text', 'Markdown'); ?>
```

If you don't want your original code to feel like "hackery" -- turn it into a feature. Add a config option to the Markdown.php `$save_format = 'html'` or `$save_format = 'markdown'` then check if you want to execute the stripper function or not. In fact, you could be really smart and turn all of this into a function inside of Markdown.php (and remember to tell the author about your new feature, he might even update his original code ;)

```
function set_save_format($format) {

  if ($format == 'markdown') {
    // Ok we need to change the format of any comments output to html:
    add_filter('comment_text', 'Markdown');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess u can use the http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/comment_save_pre-hook to manipulate the data.

Comment: I don't need to manipulate the data when saving, I need the the original markdown data to be preserved.  I don't think the comment_save_pre hook is useful.